# Need proper syntax of Begin, Commit and RollBack transaction in php mysqli

Tags: javascript, php

In my code i have generated one ledger code and that should be unique for each new insert record so after pressing submit button, it is posting all values of textbox including that "Generated Code" so i have called that `GenerateCode()` function again to create unique code at the time of Begin and Commit.

Please give me guideline that whether i have put that Begin and Commit at right place and how can i generate that unique ledger code for each insert record even if multiple users inserting record at a time??? Also, please tell me is there any another trick for this concept???

`GenerateCode()` function is in  tag which i have called again in PHP; Also i have used `START TRANSACTION` but not working

```
<?php 
      include_once('dbConnect.php'); 
      // Insert 
     if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) 
    {                       
        $url = trim($_POST['URL']);             
        $ptype = trim($_POST['HID']);           
        $AcName = trim($_POST['LName']); 
        $Description = trim($_POST['descr']);           

          //*** Start Transaction ***//  
           mysqli_query($dbCon,"BEGIN");   

    echo "<script> alert('Function Called!!!'); GenerateCode(); </script>";   // This is Javascript function called for code Generartion again              
    $Code =  trim($_POST['code']);  // Posted that Assigned code to variable    

// Insert Query             
        $Query = "insert into ma_cal(CAL_CahId,CAL_Code,CAL_Name,CAL_Description) values ('$ptype','$Code','$AcName','$Description')";                              
   $Result = @mysqli_query($dbCon,$Query);  

       if(!$Result) 
       {
      //*** RollBack Transaction ***//                       
            mysqli_query($dbCon,"ROLLBACK"); 
            $DB_Error = "Database Error => ".mysqli_error($dbCon); 
        }           
        else
        {
          //*** Commit Transaction ***//                         
         mysqli_query($dbCon,"COMMIT");                             
          $InsertSuccess = "Done";
        }    
}  // If end  ?>
```

This is Javascript function for Code Generation which i have called in Head tag

```
< script type = "text/javascript" > function GenerateCode() {
    var id = document.getElementById("HeadAcc").value;
    var dataString = 'PID=' + id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_LedgerCode.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $("#GotCode").html(html);
        }
    });
} < /script>
```

GenerateCode() Javascript function has written for each insert Unique code generation should be there even if there are multiple users using same form at a time; Provide proper solution for this